# Fan not working

Tags: fan

The fan seems to not working in my ubuntu laptop. The hardinfo show no therm sensor. I also try use sudo pwmconfig:

```
  This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
  controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
  your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
  circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

  We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
  The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
  after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
  physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
  after the program has completed.

  /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I also try

```
     lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D',
```

the result is this

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```